# How to close/copy a specific git branch contents to a folder on another server using ssh

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have a repo on bitbucket and there are couple of branches in it. All the latest code is pushed to `release` branch after working locally. I have an instance of my website on another server which I connect using ssh. In that server there is a folder `MyWebsite`(/var/www/html/MyWebsite). I need to copy all the content from the `release` branch to folder MyWebsite so that the website functions as per the latest code.

After navigating into the MyWebsite folder using ssh, I tried using

```
git clone -b release <bit-bucket repo url>

git clone -b master  <bit-bucket repo url> release `In this case I thought the content in release branch is moved to master but I'm wrong`

git fetch -b release <bit-bucket repo url> =>  Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git error
```

Can someone help in solving this. TIA

Comment: Have you pushed your `release` branch to remote?

Comment: If you have pushed the code to remote branch "release", then do simply git pull in to your machine by connecting using ssh , if not then do scp from your local to copy the folder. below is the syntax of scp                                                       e.g .Copy the directory "foo" from the local host to a remote host's directory "bar"
 
$ scp -r foo your_username@remotehost.edu:/some/remote/directory/bar

Comment: @sajibkhan Yeah its already pushed to remote release branch on bit bucket..

Comment: @MonisMajeed Its pushed to remote release branch. And in the server, i did `git init`, and then `git add remote release <bit-bucket repo url>` and then did `git fetch release`. But then I dont see any files in the folder

Comment: you please log in to box where you want code , and run this command in terminal git clone username@git repo url and then give password when it prompts for password [you can see your git clone url , by logging in to bitbucket account ->repos]

Comment: @MonisMajeed but git clone copies all the branches . I want only the content in release branch in the ssh box

Comment: after clone run this command  git checkout <your desired branch name> and to verify whether branch got switched do git branch , it will display the checkout branch [the current branch name]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And in the server, I did `git init`, and then `git add remote release <bit-bucket repo url>` and then did `git fetch release`. But then I don't see any files in the folder

Yes, `git fetch` only fetches the history. It does not checkout any branch.

See all the branches with `git branch -avv`.

Try, on that server in your ssh session, a [`git checkout -b <branch> --track release/<branch>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt).

Note: if your remote is not called '`release`', replace `release` with the name of your remote.

Indeed, the [OP ASN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6169668/asn) added [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916357/how-to-close-copy-a-specific-git-branch-contents-to-a-folder-on-another-server-u/44917318?noredirect=1#comment76858809_44917318):

> I created a new folder again, changed the names of remote and then I tried again.
>   So now it was able to pull everything from release branch.

Comment: I'm getting an error something like this:

1.  git init
2.  git add remote server <bit-bucket repo url>
3.  git checkout -b release -- track server/release

`fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'server/release' which can not be resolved as commit?`

Do I still have to do ` git fetch server` as step 3 before `git checkout -b release -- track server/release`

Comment: @ASN replace "release" with the name of your remote. If you do `git add remote server <bit-bucket repo url>`, that means, you need to getch it first: `git fetch server`, and then checkout the branch `git checkout -b <branch> --track server/<branch>` I only used 'release' because that was the name of your remote in your question. But in your comment, you changed that name to "server". Pick one name, and use it consistently.

Comment: I did the same. Just to avoid confusion i renamed the remote as server.  So I did whatever you mentioned above but getting the same error. In server location(using ssh) , I did git init, added remote with name ` "server" and repo url`, did git fetch server and then finally did `git checkout -b <branch> --track server/<branch>. In this case I want to get all the latest code from release branch on the bitbucket repo. so it will be `git checkout -b release server/release`

Comment: I do mark the answer accepted everytime if it helps me to solve the problem. I didnt forget. :) In this case I'm still getting the same error. so asking your help again

Comment: @ASN What error did you get, what command did you type, what is the output of git branch -avv?

Comment: I got the same error as above.. `fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches. Did you intend to checkout 'server/release' which can not be resolved as commit?` But then I created a new folder again, changed the names of remote and then I tried again. so now it was able to pull everything from release branch . Thank you so much ..

Comment: @ASN Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.